# How to find the changelist creation time in a perforce sandbox

Tags: perforce, changelist

In my sandbox S, I have created a changelist X and it gets submitted to perforce as Y. From Y , I want to get the exact creation time of X. That is the first time this changelist was created.

Comment: Welcome, this is your first question. May I suggest that you edit your post and start by explaining the problem, followed by everything you have already tried to resolve it and conclude with you expectation. Keep each question focused on a single problem and provide as much information as possible to attract attract a knowledgeable user with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The unit of versioning in Perforce is the submitted changelist; there is not generally a detailed record of everything that happened in the workspace prior to the submit, including edits made to the changelist while it was in a pending state.  (If you want more fine-grained versioning, submit more fine-grained changelists.)

That said, if you're willing to do the work, you can parse this information out of the server journal files (which are primarily used for server recovery rather than end-user consumption, but since they represent a plaintext record of every database transaction you can mine a LOT of data out of them if you've got access and a good understanding of the server database schema).  Look for modifications to the `db.change` table; each one is timestamped.  If you need to know when files were opened prior to the creation of the changelist, those updates are in `db.working`.